# The n mode on "iwlist wlan0 scan"

Tags: networking, wifi, openwrt

I know how to determine if scanned AP uses B or G mode, but how to know (using "iwlist wlan0 scan") it uses N protocol ?
if I use "iw dev wlan0 scan" and see if the cell has a "HT capabilities" block.

OK. "iw dev wlan scan" partially works, but i can not get data about the signal quality,  Channel mode (is it master or ad hoc) and security options.
I need to find all security algorithm options in one command.

Is there other options? like third party commands?
Any source code hack suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No tool other than `iw` can give you more information. `iw` already gives all information that the network driver gives. If some information is missing, update your network driver (that mean your kernel) and/or `iw`.

An example of an up-to-date `iw` output:

```
BSS 42:42:42:42:42:42 (on w0)
    TSF: 4922636642679 usec (56d, 23:23:56)
    freq: 2437
    beacon interval: 102
    capability: ESS ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0421)
    signal: -80.00 dBm
    last seen: 600 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: bestSSIDevar
    Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 6.0 9.0 11.0* 12.0 18.0 
    DS Parameter set: channel 6
    TIM: DTIM Count 0 DTIM Period 1 Bitmap Control 0x0 Bitmap[0] 0x0
    ERP: <no flags>
    Extended supported rates: 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
```

To get signal quality, just look at the `signal:` line.
The type of BSS is given in the `capability:` line: ESS mean this is an part of a larger network (so it's AP mode), IBSS means the network is independent, so it's ad-hoc mode.

Security options are one complex beast, given in several Information Elements.
If you see `Privacy` in `capabilities`, the network is protected somehow. If you see an `RSN` information element, then ... the network is protected via the Robust Security Network families of protocols, more know informally as WPA2. If you see an `WPA` information element, then, it's WPA1. If you see no `RSN` or `WPA` information elements but there is `Privacy`, then it's ye old WEP.

Here is a snipped of a network supporting both WPA and RSN with both CCMP and TKIP (but only TKIP for group) and using IEEE 802.1X (not PSK):

```
BSS 46:46:46:46:46:46 (on w0)
    TSF: 4923527793080 usec (56d, 23:38:47)
    freq: 2412
    beacon interval: 102
    capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0431)
    signal: -59.00 dBm
    last seen: 872 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: bestest
    Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 6.0 9.0 11.0* 12.0 18.0 
    DS Parameter set: channel 1
    TIM: DTIM Count 0 DTIM Period 1 Bitmap Control 0x0 Bitmap[0] 0x0
    ERP: <no flags>
    RSN:     * Version: 1
             * Group cipher: TKIP
             * Pairwise ciphers: TKIP CCMP
             * Authentication suites: IEEE 802.1X
             * Capabilities: 4-PTKSA-RC 4-GTKSA-RC (0x0028)
    Extended supported rates: 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0 
    WPA:     * Version: 1
             * Group cipher: TKIP
             * Pairwise ciphers: TKIP
             * Authentication suites: IEEE 802.1X
             * Capabilities: (0x0000)
```

Comment: Signal quality is not the same as Signal strenght. Signal quality is signals signal/noise ratio and other parameters. It is newer the same. Also channel mode is not reported straight way as in "iwlist wlan0 scan" . in "iwlist wlan0 scan" mode parameter tells either it is Master Mode, Ad-Hoc, Mesh, etc...

Comment: @JustinBibys: No tool gives directly the signal quality with current kernels. You will have to use the survey results as well (`iw dev w0 survey dump`). (no, the value reported by `iwconfig` is a complete joke)