# I cannot enter into an wlan ap created on raspberry with my android phone, but it works on windows

Tags: linux, raspbian, android, wlan, access-point

I have a Raspberry PI Zero W with Raspbian on it. I have created with it a WLAN-AP. I can access it with my Windows 10 computer without any problems, with my Android 8.1.0 phone it don't work. The phone stops connecting after a short time (max. 2 seccounds) without any error message.

These are the information of the AP, when u scan it with `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan`

```
BSS b8:27:eb:64:ab:17(on wlan0)
    TSF: 603438314 usec (0d, 00:10:03)
    freq: 2422
    beacon interval: 100 TUs
    capability: ESS Privacy SpectrumMgmt ShortSlotTime (0x0511)
    signal: -83.00 dBm
    last seen: 0 ms ago
    Information elements from Probe Response frame:
    SSID: WLAN-AP
    Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 18.0 24.0 36.0 54.0
    DS Parameter set: channel 3
    Country: DE     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
            Channels [1 - 13] @ 20 dBm
    Power constraint: 0 dB
    TPC report: TX power: 17 dBm
    ERP: Barker_Preamble_Mode
    Extended supported rates: 6.0 9.0 12.0 48.0
    RSN:     * Version: 1
             * Group cipher: CCMP
             * Pairwise ciphers: CCMP
             * Authentication suites: PSK
             * Capabilities: 1-PTKSA-RC 1-GTKSA-RC (0x0000)
    HT capabilities:
            Capabilities: 0x21
                    RX LDPC
                    HT20
                    Static SM Power Save
                    RX HT20 SGI
                    No RX STBC
                    Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                    No DSSS/CCK HT40
            Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
            Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 16 usec (0x07)
            HT RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-7
            HT TX MCS rate indexes are undefined
    HT operation:
             * primary channel: 3
             * secondary channel offset: no secondary
             * STA channel width: 20 MHz
             * RIFS: 0
             * HT protection: non-HT mixed
             * non-GF present: 0
             * OBSS non-GF present: 1
             * dual beacon: 0
             * dual CTS protection: 0
             * STBC beacon: 0
             * L-SIG TXOP Prot: 0
             * PCO active: 0
             * PCO phase: 0
    Extended capabilities: Extended Channel Switching
```

What I have found, that the problem coud be, that android often don't support Ad-Hoc-Wlan. When I understand [The n mode on "iwlist wlan0 scan"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63069/the-n-mode-on-iwlist-wlan0-scan) right, `capability: ESS [...]` shows, that it is not Ad-Hoc....

`sudo iwconfig wlan0` show:

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11  Mode:Master  Tx-Power=31 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:on
```

Maybe you have any ideas, what is wrong with and how to correct it?

(PS: DNS and DHCP is setted up on the Raspberry and are working)

`isc-dhcp-server log`:

```
Dec 19 10:46:30 webcam dhcpd[646]: Wrote 1 leases to leases file.
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]: No subnet declaration for eth0 (192.168.0.56).
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[649]: Server starting service.
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam isc-dhcp-server[628]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpd.
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: Wrote 0 NA, 0 TA, 0 PD leases to lease file.
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: No subnet6 declaration for eth0 (fe80::2e0:4eff:fe37:e6da).
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    you want, please write a subnet6 declaration
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: No subnet6 declaration for wlan0 (fe80::ba27:ebff:fe64:ab17).
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    you want, please write a subnet6 declaration
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. **
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: exiting.
Dec 19 10:46:35 webcam isc-dhcp-server[628]: Starting ISC DHCPv6 server: dhcpd6check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
```

`dnsmasq.log`:

```
Dec 19 10:46:27 webcam systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Dec 19 10:46:27 webcam dnsmasq[507]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: started, version 2.76 cachesize 150
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: DNS service limited to local subnets
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: reading /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
Dec 19 10:46:29 webcam dnsmasq[545]: Too few arguments.
Dec 19 10:46:29 webcam systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

`hostapd.log`:

```
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam hostapd[509]: Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd.
Dec 19 10:46:44 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Dec 19 10:46:44 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Dec 19 10:52:54 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Dec 19 10:52:54 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
```

Comment: need more info. how did you set dhcp, dns, hostapd? their log?

Comment: i have added an answer with the logs, they where too long to put them here

Comment: for each try to connect my phone,to the hostapd-log will be added:

`
Dec 19 11:00:31 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Dec 19 11:00:31 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated`

Comment: Connecting with my computer, the dhcp log will get some new entries about new dhcp-address binding, the hostapd-log will be added:

`
Dec 19 11:02:27 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA a0:d3:7a:d1:fe:61 IEEE 802.11: associated
Dec 19 11:02:27 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA a0:d3:7a:d1:fe:61 RADIUS: starting accounting session 5C1A2185-00000014
Dec 19 11:02:27 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA a0:d3:7a:d1:fe:61 WPA: pairwise key handshake completed (RSN)`

Comment: That wifi you created does not have access to the Internet, right?

Comment: The Raspberry has connection to the Internet (by eth0), and with the Windows 10 computer i can access the internet throu the WLAN AP too....

Answer (score -1):

isc-dhcp-server log:

```
Dec 19 10:46:30 webcam dhcpd[646]: Wrote 1 leases to leases file.
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]: No subnet declaration for eth0 (192.168.0.56).
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[646]:
Dec 19 10:46:31 webcam dhcpd[649]: Server starting service.
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam isc-dhcp-server[628]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpd.
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: Wrote 0 NA, 0 TA, 0 PD leases to lease file.
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: No subnet6 declaration for eth0 (fe80::2e0:4eff:fe37:e6da).
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: ** Ignoring requests on eth0.  If this is not what
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    you want, please write a subnet6 declaration
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    to which interface eth0 is attached. **
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: No subnet6 declaration for wlan0 (fe80::ba27:ebff:fe64:ab17).
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    you want, please write a subnet6 declaration
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. **
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]:
Dec 19 10:46:33 webcam dhcpd[704]: exiting.
Dec 19 10:46:35 webcam isc-dhcp-server[628]: Starting ISC DHCPv6 server: dhcpd6check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
```

dnsmasq-log:

```
Dec 19 10:46:27 webcam systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Dec 19 10:46:27 webcam dnsmasq[507]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: started, version 2.76 cachesize 150
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: DNS service limited to local subnets
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: reading /run/dnsmasq/resolv.conf
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: using nameserver 192.168.0.1#53
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam dnsmasq[544]: read /etc/hosts - 6 addresses
Dec 19 10:46:29 webcam dnsmasq[545]: Too few arguments.
Dec 19 10:46:29 webcam systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
```

hostapd-log

```
Dec 19 10:46:28 webcam hostapd[509]: Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd.
Dec 19 10:46:44 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Dec 19 10:46:44 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
Dec 19 10:52:54 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: associated
Dec 19 10:52:54 webcam hostapd: wlan0: STA 88:75:98:4b:ef:f2 IEEE 802.11: disassociated
```

Comment: Please edit the question for adding data. This is an answer field.

Comment: i wanted to do it, but the logs are to long....